# (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

Tags: asp.net

i am writing common business logic class in App_code folder for connecting to database using EFW.but showing the following error     " Error    1   The type or namespace name 'job' could not be found"

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Data;



 namespace WebApplication6.App_Code
    {
        public class BlCommon
        {  
            public List<job> GetJobs()
            {
                pubs2012Entities pubsobject = new pubs2012Entities();
                var x = pubsobject.jobs.ToList<job>();
                return x;
            }
        }
    }


and class generated by EFW from jobs table is

namespace WebApplication6.App_Code

    {
        using System;
        using System.Collections.Generic;

        public partial class job
        {
            public short job_id { get; set; }
            public string job_desc { get; set; }
            public byte min_lvl { get; set; }
            public byte max_lvl { get; set; }
        }
    }
```

Comment: So what is job ?? It will be a class name i think ??

Comment: yes..it is an entity...

Comment: You did not generat job with a namespace that is the problem.
See my answer.

Answer (score 2):

Seem you dont have a reference to assembly wich contain mentioned class

Comment: yah i have added namespace.please check again

Comment: Add a Reference to dll produced by project where your class are placed

Answer (score 0):

Ok I got it:

```
Public List<job> GetJobs()
{
      pubs2012Entities pubsobject = new pubs2012Entities();
        var x = pubsobject.jobs.ToList<job>();
        return x;

}
```

Click on Job, Move the **mouse** cursor over the blue dash that appear at the bottom of
  job click Generate Class and then move your Job.cs code to your new job.cs class and
    delete the old one.
[image: This is image]

Comment: Click on job and you will se a blue dash move mouse over blue dash